# Does the term adjacent selector exist?

Tags: css, css-selectors, terminology

MDN in this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) talks about using adjacent sibling combinator and the [specs.](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#adjacent-sibling-combinators) talk about combinators too but they never call the two selectors combined by the adjacent combinator a selector. People commonly call the result of the adjacent combinator an adjacent selector, is that informal use of the term?

Comment: Never heard it referred to as "adjacent selector", but I have heard it called and referred to it myself as the "adjacent **sibling** selector". W3Schools (which has no relation to W3C) also refer to them as [sibling selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp). W3Schools is not as bad as they once were but there are more reliable sources out there like MDN which you are already aware of

Comment: Would using combinators count as a selector? I do see other sources saying yes, but the specs. do not categorize them as selectors. @Jon P

Comment: Yes, the whole thing,e.g : `.a + .b` counts as a selector, made up of other selectors : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors

Comment: Also to further quote the MDN, emphasis mine : "Combinators
The final group of **selectors** combine other selectors in order to target elements within our documents. The following for example selects paragraphs that are direct children of <article> elements using the child combinator (>):"

Comment: I see, I think I misunderstood the specs. as well. The link I had put for the specs. leads to a section about selectors and combinators falls under them, which now I see. @Jon P

Comment: Would adjacent sibling selector be the official term then? The specs. do not mention but other third-party sites do like you mentioned. @Jon P.

Comment: "combinator" seems to be the official term as per the spec.

Answer (score 0):

The terms "child selector" and "adjacent sibling selector" were old terminology used by the CSS2 spec when "selector" was a much looser term (it still is, but they use it more consistently now). It's related to "contextual selector" which is what CSS1 called selectors that used the descendant combinator. CSS2 introduced the term "combinator" to refer to the symbols themselves, but combinators themselves technically aren't selectors because they don't select anything on their own; instead, they indicate relationships between two (or more) selectors. MDN is not really correct in calling combinators selectors, but then again, it's all just semantics.

To answer your question, yes, "adjacent sibling selector" is an informal term. You can probably get away with using it even today, as it's easier to say by far than something like "a pair of compound selectors with the adjacent sibling combinator". Selectors 4 uses the much clearer and unambiguous name "next-sibling combinator" by the way.

To put it into examples:

- `+` is the adjacent sibling combinator (next-sibling combinator in Selectors 4), and
- `E + F` is an adjacent sibling selector (next-sibling selector) matching any `F` that directly follows an `E`.